# Why are the values "undefined" in the shortcode output - tinyMCE

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, tinymce

I've successfully added a tinyMCE button to the WordPress editor for adding a column shortcode and it it all works except when I press "Insert Column" in the popup window.  The output does not correctly grab the selected values.  It outputs this into the editor:

```
[column size="undefined" last="undefined" margin="undefined" bottom="undefined"][/column]
```

Below is the script that I have so far.  Am I missing something?

```
    (function() {

    tinymce.create('tinymce.plugins.ljshortcodes', {

        init : function(ed, url) {

            /* Column */   
            ed.addButton('column', {

                title : 'Add Column',
                text  : 'Column',
                onclick : function() {

                    tb_show( 'Column Shortcode', '#TB_inline?inlineId=column-form' );

                }

            });

        },

        createControl : function(n, cm) {
            return null;
        }

    });

    tinymce.PluginManager.add('ljshortcodes', tinymce.plugins.ljshortcodes);

    jQuery(function(){

        var form = jQuery('<div id="column-form"><div id="column-box" class="form-box">\
            <div class="option-row">\
                <div class="desc">\
                    <label for="column-size">Size</label>\
                </div>\
                <select name="size" id="column-size">\
                    <option value="half">One Half (1/2)</option>\
                    <option value="third">One Third (1/3)</option>\
                    <option value="twothirds">Two Thirds (2/3)</option>\
                    <option value="fourth">One Fourth (1/4)</option>\
                    <option value="threefourths">Three Fourths (3/4)</option>\
                    <option value="fifth">One Fifth (1/5)</option>\
                    <option value="twofifths">Two Fifths (2/5)</option>\
                    <option value="threefifths">Three Fifths (3/5)</option>\
                    <option value="fourfifths">Four Fifth (4/5)</option>\
                    <option value="full">Full (1/1)</option>\
                </select>\
            </div>\
            <div class="option-row">\
                <div class="desc">\
                    <label for="column-last">Last In Row?</label>\
                </div>\
                <select name="last" id="column-last">\
                    <option value="half">No</option>\
                    <option value="third">Yes</option>\
                </select>\
            </div>\
            <div class="option-row">\
                <div class="desc">\
                    <label for="column-margin">Remove All Margin?</label>\
                </div>\
                <select name="margin" id="column-margin">\
                    <option value="yes">No</option>\
                    <option value="no">Yes</option>\
                </select>\
            </div>\
            <div class="option-row">\
                <div class="desc">\
                    <label for="column-bottom">Remove Bottom Margin?</label>\
                </div>\
                <select name="bottom" id="column-bottom">\
                    <option value="yes">No</option>\
                    <option value="no">Yes</option>\
                </select>\
            </div>\
        </div>\
        <p class="submit">\
            <input type="button" id="column-submit" class="button-primary" value="Insert Column" name="submit" />\
        </p>\
        </div>');

        var column_form = form.find('#column-form');

        form.appendTo('body').hide();

        form.find('#column-submit').click(function(){

            var options = { 
                'size'      : '',
                'last'      : 'no',
                'margin'    : 'yes',
                'bottom'    : 'yes'
            };

            var shortcode = '[column';

            for( var index in options) {
                var value = column_form.find('#column-' + index).val();

                if ( value !== options[index] )
                    shortcode += ' ' + index + '="' + value + '"';
            }

            shortcode += '][/column]';

            tinyMCE.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', 0, shortcode);

            tb_remove();

        });

    });

})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved my problem!  Turns out that `var column_form = form.find('#column-form');` works fine, but for some reason the `form` variable was not outputting the `<div id="column-form">`.

Changed:

`var column_form = form.find('#column-form');`

.. to:

`var column_form = form.find('#column-box');`

.. and erased the `column-form` div.

So in the end, the script was not outputting the parent `<div>` with the id `column-form`.

Answer (score 0):

That is because `column_form.find('#column-' + index).val()` is returning `undefined`. When a jQuery selector does not contain any elements, calling `.val()` returns `undefined`, which means that `column_form.find('#column-' + index)` is not selecting any elements.

The find selector is not finding any child elements because `column_form` is actually an empty jQuery selection. When you set the value using `var column_form = form.find('#column-form');`, you can running `find` from the jQuery-created `<div id="column-form">...</div>` element, which finds nothing because it already points to that element.

So, simply replacing

```
var column_form = form.find('#column-form');
```

with:

```
var column_form = form;
```

should solve your problem. You could also just use `form` instead of `column_form`.

Comment: That's helpful to know, thanks!  However, I tried your solution and it still outputs undefined.  Here is my updated code: http://snippi.com/s/xjzq8vi  Is there anything else in the code that you can identify as a possible issue?  Getting so close, I can feel it.  :)

Comment: @LukeSmith It should be working, [I've copied the main logic here](http://jsfiddle.net/nrf585g9/). The alert comes up with `[column last="half"][/column]`. Try adding some `console.log`'s through the file, make sure variables are what they should be.

Comment: Just added `console.log(bottom);` and I get this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: bottom is not defined`.  I have it defined in the `options` variable, what am I missing?

Comment: Solved!  Had to do with #column-form not being outputted.  Original code was fine, but needed to refer to the #column-box div.  Thanks for your help anyhow Alexander!